# $1+2+3+\cdots+x > \text{Integral of } x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Why is $\Sigma_{n=1}^xn$, or $\frac{x^2+x}{2}$,
bigger than $\int x\ \text dx$, even though the integral of $x$ adds up more numbers than $\frac{x^2+x}{2}$ ?

Comment: The integral doesn't “add up” the numbers $x$ themselves; they are multiplied by $dx$ too. So you can't compare just like that.

Answer (score 2):

This result is apparent from looking at a graph. In the following (rough) picutre, you can see that the blue rectangles have areas $1$ and $2$. The total of their areas is thus $1+2$, while the integral $\int_0^2 x \,dx$ is only the area under the black line, which is less than the area of the combined rectangles.

The sum $1+2+\cdots+n$ is actually equal to the integral $\int_0^n \lceil x\rceil \,dx$, where $\lceil x\rceil$ is the ceiling function, which satisfies $\lceil x\rceil \geq x$ for all $x$.

The sum "adds up" $1$ all the way from $0$ to $1$, while the integral "adds up" mostly numbers smaller than $1$ over that same interval.

[image: Note that the blue rectangles stick out above the black line.]

Answer (score 1):

As @Theophile said, the sum $1+2+3+\cdots+x$ are the rectangles like a 'staircase', while the $x$ is like a smooth slope, as shown in this [graph from Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pqv0ufszqi).

The integral of $x$, which is $\frac{x^2}{2}$ approximates the slope by adding up infinitely many rectangular 'strips' of infinitely small length. As the number of 'strips' increases, the 'strips' better approximate the smooth slope of $y = x$. Therefore, when we add **infinitely many 'strips'**, the area of $x$ will be **exactly the same** as $1+2+3+\cdots+$.

However, in this case, the *rectangles have a width of $1$*. Since the width of the 'strips' is not infinitely small, there will be some extra area between the two functions.